# Adding page-layout-aware horizontal lines to a ReportLab table layout

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm building a PDF using ReportLab, with a Table containing most of the content.

To help distinguish rows visually, I'd like to put a horizontal line after every row, **as long as it is not the last row on a page**.

To put a horizontal line after *every* row, I could just use a TableStyle:

```
style = TableStyle([
     ("LINEBELOW", (0,0), (-1,-1), 1, colors.black),
   ])
t = Table(data)
t.setStyle(style)
```

..but using TableStyles for this doesn't seem possible, because at that point ReportLab won't know the page layout of my content.

Is there some way of doing it with the `onFirstPage` and `onLaterPages` parameters to `doc.build`?

Answer (score 2):

But it should work:  that's the beauty of `-1`:  it will be the last row/column no matter what.  The only real trick is how to eliminate the line after the last row.  To do it, just change the coordinates where your "LINEBELOW" ends.  That is, your tuple should look like this:

```
("LINEBELOW", (0, 0), (-1, -2), 1, colors.black)
```

This will make sure it applies up to row `-2`, i.e. the next to last row.  This should give you exactly what you want.

**ETA 2011/4/6**

Ah, what you need is `splitlast`.  It should work if you add a style command after your existing "LINEBELOW" command thus:

```
("LINEBELOW", (0, 'splitlast'), (-1, 'splitlast'), 0, colors.black)
```

Or pick whatever color you want, as long as you set the size to 0.

Comment: I want to omit the LINEBELOW for the last row _on each page of the PDF_ (the table spans many pages).  Changing it to (-1, -2) only removes the line below the last row in the table.

Comment: Oh.  Here's the relevant part from the documentation: "In any style command the first row index may be set to one of the special strings 'splitlast' or 'splitfirst' to indicate that the style should be used only for the last row of a split table, or the first row of a continuation. This allows splitting tables with nicer effects around the split."

Comment: Thanks, that gets me closer.  Still doesn't work though.  :-(

I know later table commands are supposed to override earlier ones, but the LINEBELOWs appear to be additive: drawing a line with weight 0 doesn't erase the line with weight 1.  I also tried `("LINEBELOW", (0, 'splitlast'), (-1, 'splitlast'), 1, colors.white)` -- which resulted in a gray line (white over black).

This got me looking in the right direction though.  I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78450/python-reportlab-use-of-splitfirst-splitlast/94869#94869 and it looks like a similar subclassing approach might work.

Comment: So I'm doing this now: http://pastebin.com/j4QrLMaL -- it isn't exactly right, but it seems to be close (if hideous).

Comment: Hmm, looking at your code, I suppose LINEABOVE and splitfirst won't do the job either.